# Magento2.3.5: How to override \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index Controller?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, controllers, magento-enterprise-2

I was trying to override \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index controller.

I created a **di.xml** file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index" type="Test\Checkout\Controller\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart\Index" />
</config>
```

and created controller **Test\Checkout\Controller\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart\Index.php**

```
 <?php

namespace Test\Checkout\Controller\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;

    const FREE_INCLUSIONS = 'additionalServices/general/free_inclusions';

    public function __construct(
        FormKey $formKey,
        Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart
        );
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $free_inclusions =  array_filter(explode(',', $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::FREE_INCLUSIONS, $storeScope)));
      
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

but I'm still getting an error like **Type Error occurred when creating object**.

Can anyone help me out to override

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace below code in your file

```
<?php

namespace Test\Checkout\Controller\Rewrite\Checkout\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;

    const FREE_INCLUSIONS = 'additionalServices/general/free_inclusions';

    public function __construct(
        FormKey $formKey,
        Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart,
            $resultPageFactory
        );
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $free_inclusions =  array_filter(explode(',', $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::FREE_INCLUSIONS, $storeScope)));
      
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

In parent __construct() you have to pass one more argument **$resultPageFactory**. Add that and try to run below commands once and try check.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for your help